# Redirect https to http using htaccess in opencart

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, opencart

I have installed opencart 2.0.1.1 and I need to redirect the https://www.domain.com to http://www.domain.com. How do I achieve it using htaccess file.

I have tried this code in htaccess file. But this doesn't work.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

How should I redirect the https URL to http. I also checked config.php file in opencart it doesn't contain any https URL.

The existing htaccess file of opencart contains the following code

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

But the file is not a htaccess file. Its only a text document named as htaccess.txt.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What specifically doesn't work?

Comment: When I run https url it doesn't redirect to http.

Comment: That should work.  Are you sure your server is configured to allow .htaccess files?  Do you have other htaccess files in use?

Comment: yes I allow htaccess file to work. I tried redirecting index.php file it works in that case but it doesnt work when I redirect to http

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last one ;)

You can try to put this code, change for your domain

In the files config.php and admin/config.php change the reference to https, replace  "http".

```
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'http S://www.example.com/');
define('HTTPS_IMAGE', 'http S://www.example.com/image/');
```

replace

```
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'http://www.example.com/');
define('HTTPS_IMAGE', 'http://www.example.com/image/');
```

My htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

# Prevent Directoy listing 
Options -Indexes

# Prevent Direct Access to files
<FilesMatch "(?i)((\.tpl|\.ini|\.log|(?<!robots)\.txt))">
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

# SEO URL Settings
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yourDomain.com
RewriteRule ^ http://yourDomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]


RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^system/download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

regards,

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution:

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yourDomain.com
 RewriteRule ^ http://www.yourDomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Or , if your prefer don't use www ,

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yourDomain.com
 RewriteRule ^ http://yourDomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

And, in the admin panel:

system->settings->server-> ssl=  NO

Regards,

Comment: This doesn't work. The SSL in admin panel is turned off.  I wrote this code by creating a new htaccess file. Is it the right way? or should I write this code in this code in the existing htaccess.txt file?

Answer (score 0):

yes, ok
I thought that you had a "correct" htaccess. Please make the following:

Create a new file .htaccess or rename the htaccess.txt to .htaccess . The "dot" in the name of the file is important. ".htaccess" (I recomend you rename the file)

put that file first
RewriteEngine On

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yourDomain.com
RewriteRule ^ http://www.yourDomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Or , if your prefer don't use www ,

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yourDomain.com
 RewriteRule ^ http://yourDomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

And, in the admin panel:

system->settings->server-> ssl= NO
system->settings->server-> Url SEO -> YES

Please, try again :)
regards,

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But again I have a doubt if I change the existing htaccess.txt file what about the code which is already present in it. Since I am new to opencart and also htaccess files kindly bear with me

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to the .htaccess file, it should redirect to what you have in the config files.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```